# How to find a replace newline and commas in a file using regex function in gedit?

Tags: xubuntu, gedit, regex

i have a text file :

```
"postalAddress2": "Postal Address Line 2",
"postalCity": "Postal City",
"postalPostCode": "Postal Code",
"postalState": "State",
```

i need to remove the second column, ie, watever that comes after the ' : ' and remove newline

expected output

```
"postalAddress2","postalCity","postalPostCode","postalState"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this with a bash command line
If really needed, this could also be scripted inside Gedit with it's 'external tools' addon

afile.txt

```
"postalAddress2": "Postal Address Line 2",
"postalCity": "Postal City",
"postalPostCode": "Postal Code",
"postalState": "State",
```

A needed command line could be like this :

```
cut -d ':' -f1 /path/to/afile.txt | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,*$//g'
```

`cut -d ':' -f1` extract first field, delimited by `:`
`tr '\n' ','` replaces `\n` by `,`
`sed 's/,*$//g'` deletes trailling comma(s)

Answer (score 1):

At least with gedit 3.28.1, you can use a regex like `:[^,]*,\n?`

Ex.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Elegant !  OP may deserves some explanations. I would replace `\n?` with `$`